# Schema Not Getting Exported on EJB Deployment Without Error

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I have Created one EJB program with a POJO class "Employee ", but on Deploying the EJB to the JBOSS 7.1 AS server , it is not creating Schema(Schema not Exported ) without any Error .

Can Any One Advice , what is wrong with the program .

**Server Logs.**

> 18:43:34,445 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar" 18:43:34,456 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876:
>   Starting deployment of "FirstEJBProject.jar" 18:43:34,587 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011401: Read
>   persistence.xml for FirstEJBProject 18:43:34,632 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011402: Starting
>   Persistence Unit Service 'FirstEJBProject.jar#FirstEJBProject'
>   18:43:36,284 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC
>   service thread 1-5) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {4.0.1.Final} 18:43:36,375 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service
>   thread 1-5) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final} 18:43:36,385 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found 18:43:36,393 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist 18:43:36,556 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-5)
>   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [   name: FirstEJBProject
>     ...] 18:43:36,993 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator]
>   (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection
>   provider:
>   org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
>   18:43:37,939 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread
>   1-5) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
>   18:43:38,003 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator]
>   (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000268: Transaction strategy:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
>   18:43:38,013 INFO 
>   [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC
>   service thread 1-5) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   18:43:38,306 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service
>   thread 1-5) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final 18:43:39,301 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015951: Admin console
>   listening on http://:9990 18:43:39,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as]
>   (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes"
>   started in 9361ms - Started 180 of 260 services (78 services are
>   passive or on-demand) 18:43:39,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed
>   "FirstEJBProject.jar"

**Persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="FirstEJBProject">

    <jta-data-source>java:/XE</jta-data-source>
    <class>Persistance.Employee</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto" value="create"/>


    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

***Employee POJO class :***

```
package Persistance;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    public Employee() {
        }


    private int idEmployee;
    private String nameEmployee;
    private String lastNameEmployee;
    private Date dateNaissance;
    private String function;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getIdEmployee() {
        return idEmployee;
    }
    public void setIdEmployee(int idEmployee) {
        this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
    }
    public String getNameEmployee() {
        return nameEmployee;
    }
    public void setNameEmployee(String nameEmployee) {
        this.nameEmployee = nameEmployee;
    }
    public String getLastNameEmployee() {
        return lastNameEmployee;
    }
    public void setLastNameEmployee(String lastNameEmployee) {
        this.lastNameEmployee = lastNameEmployee;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getDateNaissance() {
        return dateNaissance;
    }
    public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    }
    public String getFunction() {
        return function;
    }
    public void setFunction(String function) {
        this.function = function;
    }
    public Employee(String nameEmployee, String lastNameEmployee,
            Date dateNaissance, String function) {
        super();
        this.nameEmployee = nameEmployee;
        this.lastNameEmployee = lastNameEmployee;
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
        this.function = function;
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems with your deployment:

- The `persistence.xml` file use a JPA 2.1 descriptor. JBoss AS 7.1.1 supports 2.0 and lower. You should use WildFly if you want 2.1.
- The class uses the `IDENTITY` strategy for auto-generated Ids in conjunction with an Oracle10g dialect for the persistence unit. Oracle 10g does not support the concept of SQL `IDENTITY` and hence you should choose a different strategy like `SEQUENCE` or `TABLE`.